# Помогите ускорить работу запроса

Tags: mysql

Запрос вида:

```
SELECT 
users.id,
(SELECT COUNT(requests.id) FROM requests WHERE user_id = users.id OR user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users as workers WHERE workers.parent_id = users.id) ) AS `all_requests` 
FROM `users`
```

отрабатывает мега долго, но не могу придумать чем заменить

Comment: Избавляйтесь от подзапросов, используйте честный JOIN, в крайнем случае [NOT] EXISTS. И уж во всяком случае - никаких вложенных подзапросов.

Comment: через LEFT JOIN результаты множатся, может чего-то упускаю.
Например если у юзера 3 чайлда, то результат умножается на 3, есть идеи как это побороть?

SELECT 
agents.id,
(COUNT(requests.id)) AS `all_requests`
FROM `users` AS agents
LEFT JOIN users AS workers ON workers.parent_id = agents.id
LEFT JOIN requests ON requests.user_id = agents.id OR requests.user_id = workers.id
GROUP BY agents.id, requests.user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решилось такой конструкцией:

```
SELECT 
agents.id,
(COUNT(DISTINCT requests.id))
FROM `users` AS agents
left JOIN users AS workers ON workers.parent_id = agents.id
left JOIN requests  ON requests.user_id = agents.id OR requests.user_id = workers.id
GROUP BY agents.id
```